# Chat App crashes when recieving a message, is it related to firebase implementation?

Tags: android, firebase

i have implemented Firebase in my CHating app, the push notification is working but when a user receives a message while in App, it instantly closes "crash".

i have tried to change some of the dependency version to the latest, but it seems to not do any change

`

```
 these are the basic lines of code, i tried to update them to the latest 
   version then i restored them as they were in the begning, i have been 
  loking f or over 20 hours on the internet for a solution, but nothing seems to be working..
```

the app keeps on crashing everytime i recieve a message from another user.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
 compileSdkVersion 28
 buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

 defaultConfig {
     applicationId "com.chateet.chateet"
     minSdkVersion 17
     targetSdkVersion 28
     versionCode 57
     versionName '4.6'
     multiDexEnabled true

     .
     .
     .
dependencies {
 implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
 implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
 implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes.photoview:library:1.2.3'
 implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.35.0'
 implementation 'com.pkmmte.view:circularimageview:1.1'
 implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.2.0'
 implementation 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'
 implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
 implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
 implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
 implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:28.0.0'
 implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
 implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
 implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
 implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
 implementation 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
 implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.1.3'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.3.0'
 implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.0.0'
 implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.3'
 implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

~~~~ ~~~~ ~~~~ ~~~~ ~~~~ ~~~~

for the rest, I added google-services.json to my App Directory.

In addition to these files, I did not change any other file.

How can I solve the problem described above?



EDIT: 
[My LOg cat when i recieve a message : ][1]


[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuDDx.png

what are the other files i should add so ican make it more clear please? this problem is really annoying me since two days
```

Comment: Please post your codes and error logs.

Comment: Also, if you consider at some point to try using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), here you can find a tutorial on how to create a complete and functional [Firestore Chat App](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0Ak1HiH0tTPTJXsOEy-5v9qb).

Comment: @MikeM. please check my error log in the photo.

Comment: @AlexMamo please check my error log in the photo.

Comment: @elbertrivas please check my error log in the photo.